# checked collections in java

Tags: java

В java есть checked collections, по ним в документации написано

> These implementations return a dynamically type-safe view of the specified collection, which throws a ClassCastException if a client attempts to add an element of the wrong type. The generics mechanism in the language provides compile-time (static) type-checking, but it is possible to defeat this mechanism. Dynamically type-safe views eliminate this possibility entirely.

Скажем, я определил *generic collection*, компилятор заставит меня в случае необходимости скастовать явно объекты(например, в методе *add* листа).
И тогда выбросится исключение, если каст не прошел.Как ни пытайся, а положить неверный тип в генерик коллекцию не удается!

Возникает вопрос, как можно *defeat type-checking mechanism* и как в этом случае нам помогут *checked collections*?

Comment: Суровый вопрос. [Из документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection%28java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Class%29): _The generics mechanism in the language provides compile-time (static) type checking, but it is possible to defeat this mechanism with unchecked casts. Usually this is not a problem, as the compiler issues warnings on all such unchecked operations. There are, however, times when static type checking alone is not sufficient._

Comment: _For example, suppose a collection is passed to a third-party library and it is imperative that the library code not corrupt the collection by inserting an element of the wrong type._

Comment: @Regent я это читал уже, мало что понятно

Comment: Зато это ответ на поставленный выше вопрос. А более понятный пример внизу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked collection - это просто обертка над любой другой коллекцией, которая выполняет проверку типа в runtime для любой операции модификации. Пример ниже все объясняет.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();

    nums.add(1);
    nums.add(2.0);
    //nums.add("string"); compile error

    List obj = nums;

    obj.add("string");

    System.out.println(nums);

    Collection<Number> checked = Collections.checkedCollection(nums, Number.class);

    checked.add(3);
    //checked.add("string"); compile error

    Collection col = checked;
    col.add("string"); //ClassCastException
}
```

Comment: А ты попробуй ?

Comment: @Regent правильно.